# React Native callback after SocketIO response

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I have a React Native App which on `componentWillMount()` calls a function to save everything in that list.

```
var list = []
const getMatchList = (logKey) => {
  global.socket.emit("getMatches", logKey, (data) => {
    //adding to list logic
  })
  console.log("Matches Loaded");
}
class MatchesScreen extends React.Component {
  async componentWillMount() {
    logKey = await getPreferences("logKey");
    await getMatchList(logKey)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(list);
  }
}
```

When I access that screen, it shows the empty list first, then I get the message "Matches Loaded". How can I first load matches?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## whats wrong

I looks like you expect that `await` will turn your async function to a sync one, but this is not the case. Your componentWillMount *will* be called before rendering, but since it loads data asynchronously and since react will not wait for the promise to resolve, the page will be rendered with no data and will be rerendered later whenever data is available.

## how to solve

this need more context to have a good answer, but you have at least following options:

1. Use the same logic, but add a loading spinner/progress bar for that view.
2. Switch to the view when data is loaded - but it will be perceived sluggish by users.
3. If possible preload and cache the data while in previous view.